# Liveness probe failed: Get "https://10.40.8.68:10259/healthz": dial tcp 10.40.8.68:10259: connect: connection refused

Tags: kubernetes, controller, scheduler

[Liveness probe failed: Get "https://10.40.8.68:10259/healthz": dial tcp 10.40.8.68:10259: connect: connection refused](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4z4dd.png) my cluster pods like kube-scheduler and controller facing the same liveness probe issue how to fix it

while i tried to manually connecting , its connected and checking network issues and firewall checked